# animate airplane across screen

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a plane across screen - out left side - back in on right side. How can I achieve this in a In a continuos loop? So it indefinitely flys across the screen exiting out the left side and flying back in from the right side.

**My code:**

```
        html,
        body {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
        }

        #animate { 
    position: relative; 
    background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
    }

     <div id="animate"></div>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    width = "+=" + $(document).width();
    $("#animate").animate({
    left: width
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

[Code Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Ludxwja7/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the loop by recursively calling a method that does the animation.  The below snippet starts by moving the plane off the screen to the right by the page width.  It then animates to the negative width of the image.  When it's done, it waits 2 seconds before recursively calling the same method.

```js
function animatePlane ( $plane, pageWidth ) {
  $plane.css('left', pageWidth);
  $plane.animate({
    left: $plane.width() * -1
  }, 5000, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      animatePlane($plane, pageWidth);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  animatePlane($('#animate'), $(document).width());
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  width: 663px;
  height: 168px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animate"></div>
```

## CSS only solution

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100vw;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  width: 663px;
  height: 168px;
  
  animation: slideLeft 5s 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from { left: 100vw; }
  to { transform: translateX(-200vw); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animate"></div>
```

The css version using keyframes paired with the animation property to establish the animation.  It starts the image off screen, waits 2 seconds between animation, and the duration is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just do this completely with CSS animations. You'll need to use two images of your plane to create the looping effect.

To do the animation use keyframes with left going from 0 to 100% for both images. Then offset one of the images by the width of the screen minus the width of the image to create the wrapping effect.

If you don't care about the wrapping effect, you can just do from -500px to 100% and it will loop through with only needing to use 1 plane.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#plane1 {
  animation-name: fly;
}

#plane2 {
  animation-name: fly;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

@keyframes fly {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="plane1" class="plane"></div>
<div id="plane2" class="plane"></div>
```